# Reduce existing values in an array of objects to single object

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

I have a array of objects like below:-

```
arr = [{"one" :{..., details:{bikes: 5, cars: 10}}},
{"one" : {..., details:{bikes: 7, cars: 32}}},
{"one": {..., details:{bikes: 8, cars: 18}}},
{"one" : {..., details:{bikes: 9, cars: 20}}}]
```

Now, I want a result which will go through all this array of objects and will check the details and calculate the highest number of bikes and cars.

So, the output should be:-

```
output = {bikes:9, cars: 32} as highest bikes count is 9 and highest cars count is 32.
```

I can iterate through the array and keep two counter variables for bikes and cars and keep updating if I find a higher value.

But I want it in a shorter way using underscore or lodash

Comment: Those are invalid arrays.

Comment: maybe you start with a valid data structure ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested \_.max() with lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855505/nested-max-with-lodash)

Comment: updated my question

Comment: This site isn't meant to be used as a code-writing service. Have you attempted using either of those libraries? `_.maxBy` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In plain ES6 JavaScript:

```
result = {
    bikes: Math.max(...arr.map(o => o.one.details.bikes)),
    cars: Math.max(...arr.map(o => o.one.details.cars)),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

These are pretty simple one-liners

```
maxBikes = Math.max.apply(null, arr.map((x) => x.one.details.bikes))
maxCars = Math.max.apply(null, arr.map((x) => x.one.details.cars))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could address the right property and use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

```js
var array = [{ one: { details: { bikes: 5, cars: 10 } } }, { one: { details: { bikes: 7, cars: 32 } } }, { one: { details: { bikes: 8, cars: 18 } } }, { one: { details: { bikes: 9, cars: 20 } } }],
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => ({ bikes: Math.max(r.bikes, a.one.details.bikes), cars: Math.max(r.cars, a.one.details.cars) }), { bikes: 0, cars: 0 });
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash's [`_.maxBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#maxBy):

```
var output = {
  bikes: _.maxBy(arr, 'one.details.bikes'),
  cars: _.maxBy(arr, 'one.details.cars')
};
```